# Does the standard for M12 A-Coded 4-pin plugs (female) have a dummy center hole to accommodate 5-pin socket (male) connectors?

Tags: sensor, connector, standard

I have a project that will tap into an existing sensor that uses a 4-pin M12 A-Coded connector. My plan is to use a Y Splitter to allow me to tap a parallel connection to the sensor.

The splitter I have found uses 5-pin A-Coded connectors. Finding a FMM splitter has been a challenge, I haven't found a 4 pin version.

Connecting the the 4-pin sensor to the female 5-hole connector is no problem, but my concern is that the cable that is currently attached to the sensor is likely a 4 conductor cable. If the cable's connector doesn't have a dummy center hole it won't fit on the splitter. I'll have to replace the connector.

All the 4-conductor cables I've examined or seen images have a dummy center hole, is that actually part of the standard?

This may be for a large number of installations, so I won't know ahead of time each situation.

Comment: https://www.norcomp.net/series/stainless-steel-m12-series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cut off the center pin of the male connector in the Y splitter.

> The cable that is currently attached to the sensor is likely a 4 conductor cable.

It is.

> All the 4-conductor cables I've examined or seen images have a dummy center hole, is that actually part of the standard?

It is not.